# why is my data being stored in local storage, but is not displaying on the page?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm trying to save some values I input inside a text box, however, the values are stored in local storage but not on the webpage.
here's a link to the repo on github: https://github.com/malekmekdashi/work_day_scheduler

here is an example of what my code looks like:

```js
$('.saveBtn').on('click', function() {
  var inputValue = $(this).siblings('.description').val();
  var timeValue = $(this).parent('id');

  localStorage.setItem(inputValue, timeValue);
});

$('#item1.description').val(localStorage.getItem('item1'));
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row time-block">
  <div class="col-md-1 hour">9am</div>
  <textarea class="col-md-10 description" id="item1"> </textarea>
  <button class="saveBtn col-md-1"><i class="fa fa-save"></i></button>
</div>
```

Comment: `setItem(inputValue, timeValue )` is `inputValue` equal to the string `"item1"` ... that's the only way `item1` will be set in localStorage for you to retrieve it

Comment: can you elaborate a little further please

Comment: Are you certain the value is in local storage? Could you make your code into a runnable snippet so we can see the problem, and please check the syntax as the code you have given is missing a > on the textarea element.

Comment: can i send you a link to my github repo?

Comment: https://github.com/malekmekdashi/work_day_scheduler

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: *can you elaborate a little further please* - yes - check localStorage, look at what is stored under what key - the answer may surprise you

Comment: Thank you for putting up  the code - sorry I forgot that localstorage doesn't work properly in a sandboxed situation. However, it has helped me have a closer look at what you are doing. I suggest you read up on setitem and check very thoroughly what item you are setting in local storage. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem

Comment: Can I ask y’all one more question? The project I’m doing is supposed to display the accurate color in the time-block for its respective time. However, for some reason, it’s showing the whole time-block to be green. For instance, if it’s currently 3pm, the hours prior are supposed to be greyed out, and the present hour is supposed to be red and the future hours are supposed to be green. Does anyone have any idea why it’s doing that?

Comment: little update, I fixed the issue with the colorcoded timeblock, however, i'm still having the issue with local storage. it's saving in local storage, but when i refresh the page, the text on the page goes away and i dont know why. I check local storage in my console and the input values are still there.

Answer (score 0):

try this!

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font- 
   awesome/6.1.2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script 
  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
<div class="row time-block">
    <div class="col-md-1 hour">9am</div>
    <textarea class="col-md-10 description" id="inputValue"> </textarea>
    <textarea class="col-md-10 description" id="timeValue "> </textarea>
    <button class="saveBtn col-md-1"><i class="fa fa-save"></i></button>
 </div>
```

and **jQuery**!

```
$('.saveBtn').on('click', function() {
   var inputValue = $(this).siblings('.description').val();
   var timeValue = $(this).parent('id');

   localStorage.setItem("inputValue", inputValue );
   localStorage.setItem("timeValue ", timeValue );
});

$('#inputValue.description').val(localStorage.getItem('inputValue'));
$('#timeValue .description').val(localStorage.getItem('timeValue '));
```

Comment: Can I ask you one more question? The project I’m doing is supposed to display the accurate color in the time-block for its respective time. However, for some reason, it’s showing the whole time-block to be green. For instance, if it’s currently 3pm, the hours prior are supposed to be greyed out, and the present hour is supposed to be red and the future hours are supposed to be green. Does anyone have any idea why it’s doing that?